# delete overflow record per ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, delete-row

i need to have 4 records or less per ID. some ID's have more than 4 records. I need to delete the records above the limit so i have 4 records per ID.
i tried many things but the only solution i found is just deleting all the records when the ID has more than 4. 
this is my code for getting the ammount of records per ID:

```
select count(voorwerpnummer) AS plaatjes, voorwerpnummer
from Illustraties INNER JOIN items 
ON Illustraties.itemID = items.ID
INNER JOIN tbl_voorwerp 
ON items.ID = tbl_voorwerp.voorwerpnummer
group by voorwerpnummer
order by plaatjes DESC
```

i have this line to delete the extra records per itemID:

```
DELETE FROM illustraties 
WHERE plaatjefile NOT IN (select top 4 plaatjefile from illustraties where itemID = 110769395358)
AND itemID = 110769395358
```

now i need to itterate through all the itemID's which have more than 4 records.
this is how to get all the itemID's with more than 4 records:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemID ORDER BY itemID) AS rn
   FROM illustraties
)
SELECT distinct ItemID
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 4
```

can anyone make me a function or something to go through all those itemID's and execute that delete statement?
OR make a query which adds a rownumber per ID.
 
for example : an ID has 5 records. the 5 records get the numbers 1 to 5. the next ID has 8 records. the 8 records get the numbers 1 to 8.
this way i can delete the records which have an rownumber of 5 or higher.

Comment: Is it only `tbl_voorwerp` that you want to delete records from?

Comment: I need to delete from illustraties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is little known that you can delete from a CTE or derived table:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemID ORDER BY itemID) AS rn
   FROM illustraties
)
DELETE cte
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 4
```

I just changed one line. Your `ORDER BY` should really create a total order. If not SQL Server has some freedom which records to delete. Might be arbitrary and not in your interest.

Comment: what you do here is deleting the itemID's which have more than 4 records. i need to delete the extra records per itemID. for example a itemID has 5 pictures. i need to delete the 5th picture because i only need 4 of them.

Comment: @user3487046 This deletes all records where rn > 4 which is false for the first 4 records. It therefore leaves 4 records. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: i forgot i had a distinct in there so i only saw the highest rownumber. many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you need to delete records from Illustraties table.Is that possible for you to share the table structure along with Unique key fields for that table.

Comment: The table illustraties had a filename and an itemID. Primary key on filename.